# How to display multi select parameter in data item Cognos Analytics

Tags: cognos, cognos-11, report-studio

I am using IBM Cognos Analytics 11.0.13.

I want to pass a multi select parameter to a data item in a query. When I try to place the parameter in a data item, the multi select feature goes away and I can only make one selection.

For example, the end user might pass these two values through on the prompt page:

MATH101, MATH102

I want the data item in a query to return the parameter values:

MATH101, MATH102

This can be achieved in a text expression on a report page. It can also be achieved in a data item within a query if you limit the parameter to a single select.

Does anyone know how to display the parameter in a query data item when the parameter is multi select?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after a few more google searches I found the correct syntax. Enter this into your data item:

```
#sq(promptmany('Parameter1'))#
```

`'Parameter1'` is the name of your parameter.

So if an end-user enters the following into the multi-select prompt:

```
MATH101
MATH102
```

The data item created will display this:

```
'MATH101';'MATH102'
```